# Storing plaintext inside a java 8 closure

Tags: java, encryption

I once saw a talk by Douglas Crockford where, in the context of javascript, he mentioned that it could be useful to store secrets in closures.

I imagine this could be naively implemented like this in Java:

```
public static Supplier<String> passwordStore(String encryptedPassword){
    String plainTextPassword = encryptedPassword; //do some decryption
    return () -> plainTextPassword;
}
```

I wonder: Is there any benefit to doing this? Is it maybe in some way less secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very "engineered" example so **DO NOT USE IT IN YOUR CODE**.

I think the effect can be better demonstrated with a predicate rather than a supplier.

Assume you implement a password checker as follows:

```
public class PasswordChecker {

    private final String secretPassword;

    public PasswordChecker(String secretPassword) {
        this.secretPassword = secretPassword;
    }

    public boolean test(String password) {
        return Objects.equals(this.secretPassword, password);
    }

}
```

Then you can create an instance an pass it around:

```
final PasswordChecker passwordChecker = new PasswordChecker("changeit");
```

And somewhere else you could use it to check the password:

```
assertThat(passwordChecker.test("foobar")).isFalse();
```

However for the client which has an instance of `PasswordChecker` at hand, it is not so difficult to extract the password with some reflection:

```
    Field secretPasswordField = passwordChecker.getClass().getDeclaredField("secretPassword");
    secretPasswordField.setAccessible(true);
    String secretPassword = (String) secretPasswordField.get(passwordChecker);
    System.out.print(secretPassword);
```

Now here's the same thing with a closure:

```
final String secretPassword = "changeit";
final Predicate<String> passwordChecker = password -> Objects.equals(secretPassword, password);
```

Now you can't extract `secretPassword` from the `passwordChecker`.

Comment: I like this -it occurs to me that you could bake all kinds of functionality(valdiation, hashing, etc) into your predicate.

Comment: Sorry, I got "int erupted" by work, I was eating a sandwich when viewing the answers. Maybe I would have upvoted if the question started with: using a closure protects your fields against being exposed through reflection. But besides that, *verification* of passwords should be implemented using password hashes or SRP or similar. In that case the closure doesn't make sense anymore. And your code introduces a time based attack against verification of the password through the `equals` method.

Comment: If you extend the warning that the code is insecure & show a reference for your claim that reflection cannot work then I'm happy to upvote.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The question is about storing data in closure, not about secure handling of passwords. And there's a big fat warning there. It does not even make sense to talk about password security here, my answer exlains a totally different point. But thanks for clarifying the downvote, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

No reason to do that. Store the password in the array of characters, since they must be explicitly converted to String if you want to print them out.

Consider the following example:

```
String stringPassword = "password";
char[] charactersPassword = new char[]{'p','a','s','s','w','o', 'r', 'd'};

System.out.println("Password: " + stringPassword);     // Password: password
System.out.println("Password: " + charactersPassword); // Password: [C@6ce253f1
```

The main idea is you can clear the array's items, since it is not immutable (`@Klitos Kyriacou`).

```
Arrays.fill(charactersPassword, '0');
```

Moreover, if you store the password as a plain text - String, which is immutable, it will be available in the memory for a long time (which is still somehow accesible) until the Garbage collector takes care of it.

Anyway, it's highly recommended to look after some security library which can handle much more than inventing a new (usually still risky) way.

Comment: The idea of storing a password in characters is that you are able to clear them, not so much that they are directly available. It's up to the user to clear them though, and this part is missing from your answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Yes, I got it now. Thank you for the comment. :)

Comment: No, that's not how you clear it! The original array is still hanging around waiting to be garbage-collected! You need to clear the actual elements of the original array.

Comment: Setting the variable to null still leaves the original array object (containing the password) untouched. Instead, use `Java.util.Arrays.fill(charactersPassword, 0);`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I've to use `'0'` instead of `0`, because of the array of characters.

Comment: Side note: this is why [```JPasswordField.getPassword```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword()) returns an array of characters - you can get rid of them later via overwriting.

Comment: @tevemadar And *hope* that they are not stored anywhere after that; the memory allocation routines may have copied them elsewhere without clearing the original array and it may even be copied into virtual memory. Unfortunately there aren't any Java features for handling different kind of memory (secure, persistent, faster etc.) - just like many other high level languages for that matter. So clear it asap and hope for the best.